# How to use ascii characters in MuleESB Dataweave strings, £ © ¥ etc

Tags: mule, dataweave

Seems like the editor is unicode aware..but the validation throws a problem

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
funds map {
    prize_us: "\$" ++ $ as :string,
    prize_uk: "£" ++ ($ * 0.81) as :string  
}

Error in DW script: Invalid input """, expected typeOf, using, unaryOp, not or value
```

note the """ instead of the £ symbol.

Removing the £ the problem goes away and the project can compile.

Comment: Hmm actually the project compiles, its just Eclipse reporting it as a problem....might just have to manage with that...:-(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the encoding also.
`%dw 1.0
%input in0 application/json
%output application/java encoding="UNICODE"`

Comment: nope, that throws: `%output application/java encoding="UNICODE"
                                  ^
Option `encoding` is not valid. Valid options are: .`